# Excel mouse focus weirdness

Tags: excel, vba, dll, timer

I have a class based on
CSocket in a DLL which has various threaded buffers for holding the
incoming stream. I have a couple of applications with which this works
perfectly, using a timer to poll the buffer to see if anything is there
to be pulled out and then displayed.

Now I've got the timer in some VBA code, a macro if you will, in an
Excel module. The timer fires as expected but the DLL only says there's
stuff in the buffer when you hold the mouse button down on a scroll tab
or the title bar of Excel! So if you try moving the Excel window the
table starts populating with data pulled from the buffer. If you try
moving the window programmatically then it doesn't work. Somehow mouse
focus has to be on the frame of the Excel window. It also works if you
open the system menu at the top left of the window. (This is Excel 2003
SP3 BTW.)

Comment: Excel 2003 SP3 BTW --  ... Oh oh!  Microsoft's addition of BTW (Buffer-Threaded Window) Technology introduced several irritating behaviors.  I think this may be one of those.

Comment: I think you're right. Putting the DLL in it's own thread solved the problem. 

Sorry for the late update, I didn't receive notification of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

For 'accepted' answer see comment above (which I can’t transfer, which mod declined to and presumably OP is not going to). Ie:

*Put the DLL in it's own thread*.